# Highlighting Not Enabled in PDF That Allows Text Copying and Searching (Win7)

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-reader, highlighting, sticky-notes

I have a PDF of a technical paper, and I would like to highlight portions and make notes.  However, neither of those tools are enabled in Adobe Reader when I open the file (using Windows 7).

I can select and copy text from the file to paste elsewhere, as well as search the contents.  It's just highlighting and sticky notes that appear to not be working.

Why does this happen?  Is there any way I can enable highlighting and sticky notes?  I keep these files in the cloud and read them across multiple devices, including Windows, Mac OS X, Kindle Fire and an iPhone, so a cross-platform solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like there may be some restrictions on the the file you have. In other PDF files, can you do the highlights and sticky notes?

You may want to try a third party PDF reader too like [Sumatra](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) or [Foxit](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) and see if you can use the highlighting tools in those programs and what happens if you then open them back up in Adobe Reader.

Also another workaround, by default you have the XPS printer installed in windows 7. You can print the document to XPS then using something like [cutepdf printer](http://cutepdf.com/Products/CutePDF/writer.asp) (Foxit PDF comes with a virtual pritner as well) print the XPS document back to PDF. i.e. print PDF->XPS then print XPS->PDF.

Comment: Foxit fixed the issue.  I can save highlights and notes, and view them in Adobe Reader.  I just can't make new highlights in Adobe Reader, for whatever reason.